# `unlist`ing different value types in a `data.table` to a single column

Tags: r, data-structures, data.table, reshape

When trying to `unlist` a `list` column in a "data.table", where each `list` element might be of a different type, "data.table" produces an error and halts execution:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 V2 = list(c(1, 2), NA, c(10, 20, 30)))
DT[, list(unlist(V2)), V1]
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , list(unlist(V2)), V1) : 
#   Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'logical' but expecting 
#   type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

The problem there, as one can figure out from the error, is that the `NA` value isn't the specific `NA` type expected (in this case, `NA_real_`).

```
DT2 <- data.table(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                  V2 = list(c(1, 2), NA_real_, c(10, 20, 30)))
DT2[, list(V2 = unlist(V2)), V1]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  A  1
# 2:  A  2
# 3:  B NA
# 4:  C 10
# 5:  C 20
# 6:  C 30
```

***Question:*** Is there a convenient way to proceed with `unlist`ing -- even with a `warning` as is issued by `melt` when the measure variables are of different types?

```
DT3 <- data.table(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2_1 = c(1, 2, 3), 
                  V2_2 = NA, V2_3 = c(10, 20, 30))
melt(DT3, "V1")
# Warning message:
# In melt.data.table(DT3, "V1") :
#   'measure.vars' [V2_1, V2_2, V2_3] are not all of the same type. By order of 
#   hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'double'. All measure 
#   variables not of type 'double' will be coerced to. Check DETAILS in 
#   ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.
```

I'm not looking for non-data.table approaches. I already know, for instance, that `unnest()` from "tidyr" would work (and doesn't even issue a warning):

```
tidyr::unnest(DT)
#   V1 V2
# 1  A  1
# 2  A  2
# 3  B NA
# 4  C 10
# 5  C 20
# 6  C 30
```

Comment: can't you lapply (rapply?) a type conversion first, then unlist the output?

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I can, but I'd also have to know that my `NA`s are not the same type in the first place.

Comment: (And I'm not even sure how obvious it is to the average user that R has different `NA` types in the first place, even though it's in the first line of the documentation for `NA`.)

Comment: how about `DT[ , .(rep(V1, lengths(V2)), unlist(V2))]`. Can be extended to work with more columns by rep'ing .I and indexing .SD with it

Comment: indeed, also related: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1787

Comment: @MichaelChirico, works for me. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Fyi, generalization of Michael's answer is in chat from yesterday: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41268246#41268246

Comment: @Frank, somehow I missed that comment. :-/ MichaelChirico, thanks for the issue links.

Comment: HTH. I think fundamentally it's that `unlist` will coerce its output, (which I assume is why `tidyr::unnest` works without warning/error), but of course grouping in `data.table` must reassemble its results, so indeed this is a duplicate. I still wish `data.table` would have `unnest` built in, and efficiently.

Comment: @Frank, yes, I would have done `DT[ , c(.SD[rep(.I, lengths(V2))], list(unlist(V2))), .SDcols = !'V2']`, and yes, very ugly